# Android - Can't get notification to resume activity without running onCreate()

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, oncreate, resume

I have tried looking through a lot of other threads on this but none of the replies have helped me. In my displayNotification() method I already do this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

and I have also included this in the activity in the AndroidManifest file:

```
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

However, when I try to run the code I get this log:

```
07-09 16:26:44.982     726-1167/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.example.chrekm.inductivechargingcontroller/.MainActivity} from uid 10091 on display 0
07-09 16:26:45.010     726-1167/? V/WindowManager﹕ addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2a93c8d9 token=Token{14f61720 ActivityRecord{1ee92623 u0 com.example.chrekm.inductivechargingcontroller/.MainActivity t14858}}} to stack=1 task=14858 at 2
07-09 16:26:45.023     726-1167/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x24000000 cmp=com.example.chrekm.inductivechargingcontroller/.MainActivity} from uid 10091 on display 0
07-09 16:26:45.023      726-798/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{359baa38 u0 Starting com.example.chrekm.inductivechargingcontroller} at 15 of 21 (after Window{bcd3a48 u0 com.example.chrekm.inductivechargingcontroller/com.example.chrekm.inductivechargingcontroller.MainActivity})
```

The flags given to me in the log seems to be:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME - 0x00004000

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK - 0x00008000

FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK - 0x10000000

FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING - 0x20000000

FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP - 0x04000000
```

So, what am I doing wrong that makes my app open up a new instance of my main activity? This behavior disconnects my bluetooth connection which disrupts the user experience quite heavily, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I actually managed to fix the problem myself. Instead of using TaskStackBuilder I just did the following:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Less code and it works beautifully! If anyone else has the same problem, just try using PendingIntent.getActivity instead of stackBuilder.getPendingIntent.